# Is it possible to enumerate thru all the hardware IDs?

Tags: integrity, rootkits

I am thinking of developing of a rather primitive CLI program for the sole purpose of detecting rootkits/bootkits/firmware modifying advanced malware.

- Can you iterate thru all all hardware IDs (CPUID, GPUID etc) like `dmidecode` does just for ALL hardware (so including PCIe, TPM, etc etc) and generate their hashes?
- What would be required to do (or maybe there's already a tool for it?)?
- Are there another types of IDs under Windows compared to Linux?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rootkit-revealer
I've seen a hardware explorer for windows, but can't find it quickly.  The TPM does some of what you want in terms of hardware security.

Comment: Lookup for Trusted boot, which does exactly the same using TPM. TPM firmware is digitally signed and verified, so the whole process of boot is measured. However, as per your question, it is not clear at what stage you are planning to verify the hashes?

Comment: TPM actually hashes and verifies every boot stage, from firmware through operating system.  It publishes the hashes for each in a secure way, and then publishes an insecure but verifiable log of how the hashes were generated.  And then you can store secrets in the TPM locked to those hashes.

Comment: @user10489 `RwPortableX64V1.7` does this job for example. Here's a link to their website: http://rweverything.com/ But the problem is that it's not scalable to thousands of PCs/servers.

Comment: Let me clarify: my goal is make "snapshots" of the integrity of the firmware and compare in another "snapshot" in the future. If there were no firmware updates the hashes/checksums should remain the same. In the other case advanced firmware modifying malware has already infiltrated the firmware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My goal is make "snapshots" of the integrity of the firmware and compare in another "snapshot" in the future. If there were no firmware updates the hashes/checksums should remain the same. In the other case advanced firmware modifying malware has already infiltrated the firmware.

You can't do this from the OS.

Most CPUID values aren't helpful here. The CPUID data is structured into leaves and subleaves. Each is numbered, with the leaf number being passed to the `cpuid` instruction in the `eax` register, and the subleaf number being passed in the `ecx` register. I wrote [a tool for exploring CPUID values](https://cpuid.apps.poly.nomial.co.uk/) if you want to take a look at the kind of data that is stored in there.

A large portion of the values in the lower leaves are about hardware identity, hardware feature support, and cache topology. As you get a little further down the list you'll start running into feature enable flags, which are related to whether or not a feature has been enabled rather than whether or not it is actually physically supported by the hardware. These are usually mapped to bits in control registers (CR4, EFER, XCR0, etc.) or model-specific registers (MSRs). Some of the values in there change all the time, e.g. clock scaling ratios in leaf 0x15. Occasionally some of the values are security-relevant, such as whether or not SGX is enabled on the system (something that is configured from the UEFI/BIOS), but they're few and far between.

GPUID isn't an instruction or standardised interface for gathering information. There's no such thing. I suspect you're confusing it with some tool from the company named "CPUID", who make CPU-Z and GPU-Z.

Dumping information about PCI-e devices could mean a few things. You could enumerate the installed PCI-e devices using the plug-n-play APIs on Windows, or the equivalent on Linux, and dump the vendor and device IDs, but that'd only tell you if a new PCI-e device was installed. You could attempt to dump the PCI-e config space (BARs) or IO space but that's all implementation-specific data that can contain anything, may change values at runtime, and can also change due to something as innocuous as a driver update. Dumping OPROMs would tell you if those had changed, but again they could be changed with a driver update that performs an OPROM update automatically, and a smart attacker could cause the OPROM to return different data on the second read pass after the initial execution at boot time (assuming OPROMs are even enabled for the system).

There's not really anything in the TPM that can help you here either, from the OS side.

The main problem is trust. If you assume that an attacker can modify firmware (i.e. executable code existing outside of the normal storage media used to hold the operating system) and that the firmware modifications have a tangible security impact (i.e. they can modify system memory) then once they've done this you can't trust a single thing that is being reported from within the OS.

That's not to say that this isn't a real problem. This comes up all the time in the context of bare metal cloud platform security. In that industry, each customer is given a real piece of server hardware and complete access to it, for the duration of their contract. Afterwards, the hardware needs to be re-used. How do you find out whether the customer (or an attacker that compromised the customer's system) didn't modify the system in a way that persists beyond reinstallation of the OS?

The answer there mostly comes down to extensive analysis work at the hardware and firmware level, often with collaboration with the motherboard manufacturer and peripheral manufacturers. Vendors can provide statements of volatility (SoVs) that describe any non-volatile storage that exists on the device. Capabilities are then developed to access and audit those non-volatile storage locations, e.g. with board-level jigs and EEPROM readers, or at least to reinstall and verify a clean firmware state. This is a large undertaking and usually involves years of R&D by the hosting provider.

Another point to be made here is an economic one: the risk of firmware-resident malware on modern computers is negligible in most environments, and the cost of concretely verifying that such modifications have not been made is very high. In most cases, such an attack is far more likely to be caught by its side-effects (initial breach, post-exploitation behaviour, exfiltration of data, modification of system behaviour, etc.) than by the actual firmware modification. Detection measures (AV, EDR, sysmon, IPS/IDS, etc.) and defensive measures (hardened GPO, SecureBoot, VBS, WDAC/AppLocker, WDAG, Credential Guard / LSA isolation, exploit mitigation policy, 2FA, etc.) along with strong policy and procedures (network inventory, onboarding/offboarding, phishing training, incident reporting & response, etc.) all provide much more "bang for the buck" here than spending a ton of resources on the specific and unlikely threat of firmware resident malware. If you don't have this stuff already nailed down perfectly - which I can say with confidence describes about 99.9998% of all organisations out there - then trying to build capabilities in the firmware space are absolutely not worth the time and effort compared to more traditional organisational security practices. It's not sexy but it's way more effective.

Comment: Brilliant and deep answer. I am aware of firmware upgrades, I would need to take those into account as well. I was actually thinking of developing a mini-OS just for this purpose. It's more of a hobby/research project than a viable one. What would be the recommended approach for that? I am thinking to make it Linux-kernel-based but I don't know if that's the best approach when wide hardware support is required.

Comment: There's no recommended approach there. If you're tinkering, tinker with what you're most familiar with.